# Can a mobile chrome apps sync with Google Drive?

Tags: google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I've developed a Chrome Apps application for mobile. I've now implemented the syncFileSystem API which works perfectly on the desktop (as a chrome extension) but when I push the app to the mobile no syncing takes place as far as I can tell.
The mobile-chrome apps API github page says:

> syncFileSystem - store and retrieve files backed by Google Drive
>   Alpha quality on iOS and Android (not currently being worked on)
>   Does not sync when app is not running.

I just realised that I get a message when pushing the app to mobile (via cca run device) regarding the permission:

> "Permission not recognized by cca: syncFileSystem (ignoring)"

Which I believe refers to the permission of using the chrome.FileSystem API. Does anyone know if this issue can be fixed and how to fix it?
I think this issue is prohibiting syncing the data to Google Drive on mobile.

Thanks in advance!